# How can I echo the version of the current Laravel version in php using the view?

Tags: php, laravel, version

I don't want to check my Laravel version in the command prompt (`php artisan --version`), but in the view itself.

Like this:

```
<?php
  $laravel_version = /*laravel version check code*/;
?>
```

In the view:

```
{{ $laravel_version }}
```

Do anyone know how I can do that? Maybe it isn't possible..?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
$laravel = app();
$version = $laravel::VERSION;
```

Comment: There is also a method returning that const: `$version = app()->version();`

Answer (score 149):

This is the way how to see laravel version in command explorer:

```
php artisan --version
```

Comment: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in myproject/artisan

Comment: your php bin should be in window path @AbdennourTOUMI

Comment: What is the first line of the question?

Comment: Sometimes it needs to go to the project folder and then have to give the command.

Answer (score 49):

Here is an easiest way to check it manually from the folder

Go to project folder

D:\xampp\htdocs\your-project-folder\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php

const VERSION = '5.2.45'; //version of laravel
 [image]

This is the another way to check it.

If you don't want to check using this command **php artisan --version**

Answer (score 25):

In Laravel's Blade templates:

```
{{ App::VERSION() }}
```

Note that this is tested in 5.3x

Answer (score 17):

There are different ways of coding, I found multiple ways to current version find in Laravel

View current Laravel version through **Blade Templates**, there are many ways:

First way

```
{{ App::VERSION() }}
```

Second way

```
<?php
     echo $app::VERSION;
?>
```

Third way

```
<?php
  $laravel = app();
  echo $laravel::VERSION;
?>
```

Also, the Laravel version installed can be checked in the command line using the following command :

```
php artisan --version
```

Answer (score 6):

```
global $app;
echo $app::VERSION;
```

Answer (score 4):

- ubunut 16.04
- php 7.0.33
- Laravel Framework 5.5.48

  ```
  php artisan --version
  ```

  **Artisan** -Artisan is the name of the command-line interface included with Laravel. It    provides a number of helpful commands for your use while developing your application. It is driven by the powerful Symfony Console component.

**for more-**

```
    php artisan list
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code in routing file of your laravell installation

```
 $app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
return $app->version();
});
```

On view you will get installed version of laravell.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying Your Current Laravel Version

You may also view the current version of your Laravel installation using the **--version** option:

```
php artisan --version
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way that works throughout your app - Blade templates or otherwise - is to use:

```php
app()->version()
```

Answer (score 1):

Only for a specific Project Folder to know the Laravel version of that project 
on CLI

```
$  php artisan --version
```

remove `$` while copying only for representation purpose

Answer (score 1):

One More way.
Just go to the root directory of the project.

Hit below commands

```
php artisan tinker
App::VERSION()
```

Tinker is amazing.