# URL being appended to the previous URL (the older version of Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, url, redirect

I am working with the older version of Laravel and I don't which version I am working on as this project was given to me for debugging. I have zero knowledge of Laravel. Doing php artisan --version gave me this as an output in git bash [image: click here to see the out of command]
Following is the code:

```
<nav class="sidebar sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item nav-profile">
        <div class="nav-link">
          <div class="user-wrapper">
            <div class="text-wrapper">
              <p class="profile-name"><?php echo GetUserDetail::get(Session::get('admin_id'),'fullname');?> <span class="status-indicator online"></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>            
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="dashboard" style="background-color: #518be6 !important; width:250px; color: #fff !important; border-radius: 0px;">
          <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt menu-icon" style="color: #fff"></i>
          <span class="menu-title">ड्याशबोर्ड</span>
        </a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="service">
          <i class="fas fa-briefcase menu-icon"></i>
          <span class="menu-title">सेवाहरू</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="resource">
          <i class="fab fa-osi menu-icon"></i>
          <span class="menu-title">संसाधन</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="agenda">
          <i class="fab fa-forumbee menu-icon"></i>
          <span class="menu-title">परियोजना</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="profile">
          <i class="fas fa-people-carry menu-icon"></i>
          <span class="menu-title">प्रोफाइल</span>
        </a>
      </li>          <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="notice">
          <i class="fas fa-info-circle menu-icon"></i>
          <span class="menu-title">सूचना तथा जानकारी</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="add_user">
          <i class="fas fa-user-plus menu-icon"></i>
          <span class="menu-title">थप प्रयोगकर्ता</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

I tried keeping `/` just before `href` like `href="/dashboard"`. My expected output is `http://demo.com/admin/dashboard` but when I click on the link it goes like this `http://demo.com/dashboard`.

I also tried doing `href="{{ url('dashboard')}}"` which converts my URL to like this:
`http://demo.com/admin/%7B%7B%20url('dashboard')%7D%7D`

What should be done to fix this?

Comment: tried? admin/dashboard

Comment: @SayedMohdAli Yes, I tried doing that too but it gave this URL http://demo.com/admin/admin/dashboard.

Comment: run this command using cli php artisan --version and tell us the version.

Comment: read Laravel routing docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing

Comment: Check out Your routing file, if the name *dashboard* points to desired url like this `Route::get('/admin/dashboard', 'Controller@function')->name('dashboard');`

Comment: @Alisha For Current Laravel version Checking:- [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153630/how-can-i-echo-the-version-of-the-current-laravel-version-in-php-using-the-view/50384491#50384491)

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya none of the three answer given in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153630/how-can-i-echo-the-version-of-the-current-laravel-version-in-php-using-the-view/50384491#50384491) this page gave the Laravel version that I am using.

Comment: @VolmargReiso I don't have Route folder in this project. And also the file in this project are saved in .php extension, not in .blade.php.

Comment: @Alisha Read my answer there and you find out the current version of Larvael framework:- [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153630/how-can-i-echo-the-version-of-the-current-laravel-version-in-php-using-the-view/50384491#50384491)

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya The first did not do any changes, the second way says undefined variable $app, the third way says a call to undefined function app(). The last one php artisan --version gave the output which I have added in my question.

Comment: @Alisha You cannot use `php artisan` if you are not inside a **laravel** project folder. 
That is why it says **Could not open input file - artisan** check your question error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187732/discussion-between-udhav-sarvaiya-and-alisha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your short fix would be this,

```
href="/admin/dashboard"
```

The problem was with the way html use href attribute. When you put '/' (forward slash) at the very beginning it starts from the root directory not from the current directory.

However this is a bad practice. You should study [routing method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing) and [url generation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls) . For large project your url controller will be much easier.

(I don't know your version of laravel. So I provided the link of the latest version. But you can change it from menu.)